# Why does my FusionCharts chart not go to its initial date?

Tags: javascript, fusioncharts

I am trying to build a very simple chart using FusionCharts where I can show data in a time-axis chart. I followed [examples on the official website](https://www.fusioncharts.com/dev/fusiontime/fusiontime-component/time-axis), but my chart won't jump to the set initial date for the x-axis. Instead, my chart is initially set to January 1970, which to my knowledge is the minimum date value on UNIX-based machines.

```js
const data = [["2020-01-01",0],["2020-01-02",2],["2020-01-03",6],["2020-01-06",4],["2020-01-07",12],["2020-01-08",13],["2020-01-10",5],["2020-01-11",23],["2020-01-20",26],["2020-01-21",22],["2020-01-22",17],["2020-01-23",30],["2020-01-24",27],["2020-01-28",28],["2020-02-02",23],["2020-02-03",33]]
const schema = [{"name":"Date","type":"date","format":"%d-%b-%y"},{"name":"Value","type":"number"}]

const dataStore = new FusionCharts.DataStore();
const dataSource = {
  chart: {},
  caption: {
    text: "Sales Analysis"
  },
  subcaption: {
    text: "Grocery"
  },
  yaxis: [
    {
      plot: {
        value: "Grocery Sales Value"
      },
      format: {
        prefix: "$"
      },
      title: "Sale Value"
    }
  ],
  xaxis: {
    initialinterval: {
      from: '2020-01-01',
      to: '2020-01-31',
    }
  }
};
dataSource.data = dataStore.createDataTable(data, schema);

new FusionCharts({
  type: "timeseries",
  renderAt: "chart-container",
  width: "100%",
  height: "500",
  dataSource: dataSource
}).render();
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to set the date time format correctly based on the date time you are passing.

Check the following correct date-time format in your schema.

```
const schema = [{"name":"Date","type":"date","format":"%Y-%m-%d"},{"name":"Value","type":"number"}]
```

Also check the following modified sample http://jsfiddle.net/t7y3upoj/1/

Comment: It indeed seemed like I had to set my date time format correct in the schema I passed and match it with the data I give. Thank you

Comment: Glad it is helpful please upvote the answer :)